# When I use create function of Monaco Editor, it comes out "contextKeyService.ts:393 Element already has context attribute"

Tags: requirejs, monaco-editor

HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/opt/require.js" data-main="/static/opt/demo"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/opt/demo.js"></script>
<script src="/static/opt/monaco-editor/package/min/vs/loader.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="padding: 0;display: inline-flex;margin-left: 175px">
        <div id="input_editor" ></div>
    </div>
    
    <div  class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="margin-left:165px;display: inline-flex">
        <div id="show_editor" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

demo.js

```
require.config({paths:{'vs':'/static/opt/monaco-editor/package/min/vs'}});

$(document).ready(function () {
   
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function(){
        var input_editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("input_editor"), {
            value: "aaa"
        })
    })
    
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function(){
        var show_editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("show_editor"), {
            value: "bbbbb"
        })
    })
})
```

Is there anything wrong in my code? How should I use monaco editor in HTML?
And is there any api to color somelines red or green in the Monaca Editor?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-amd.md I think you should give it a try and copy the code from the docs